# Can I place an email in iOS's outbox (preferably with MonoTouch)?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I would like to place an email in the iPhones email outbox, without showing the compose window to the user, so that he can not mess with the data that I want to send. Is this possible?

Thanks,
Timo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - if you want to send an email using the user's email account you must allow them to modify the message contents: that's part of Apple's message framework. To be honest, it's a fairly sensible feature...I don't think many people would want an app that could just send things out without alerting the user or allowing them to modify it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send a message and stop the user from messing with your data, just add an attachment and check for the attachment on the backend (assuming that because you want to send specific data)